# "presentViewController" and Orientation problems between iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: sdk, layer, uiinterfaceorientation, ios8, presentviewcontroller

In iOS 6 or 7 sdk,
[image: myV Setting]
I can be effectively "presentViewController" and handle the presentedViewcontroller's Orientation.

I try to use Landscape VC to present Portrait VC, and It's Work at iOS sdk 6-7.

[[self viewController] presentViewController:dotWebView animated:YES completion:nil];

but
when I turn on iOS 8 simulator and build my project, 
the presented VC can not handle it's own Oritation any more.
It's always Landscape Ori and never come back.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

still not working effectively, because the keyboard only eat   [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] , and I have no way to change it by coding.

I have ever use view.layer.transfrom to change the angle (M_PI/2)
but only Self-satisfaction.

I still can not turn it on....
If anyone knew about the possibility of teaching?

Comment: Hi, are u resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning
I download Xcode 6 Beta4
and
It's no problem＠＠

Comment: i'm having the problem in the release of ios 8. is it still resolved for you?